# Set Default value for a CR 8.5 parameter using VB6.0

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I need help in CR 8.5 using VB6.0
I want to set default values for a crystal report parameter in VB6.0 .
Is it possible? 
Using Crystal Report 8.5 , Visual Basic 6.0.

Comment: I don't see why not. Show us some code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Agreed, code samples are definitely needed.

Comment: Which parameter did you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
Dim CrParameter as ParameterFieldDefinition

For Each CrParameter in CrReport.ParameterFields
    If CrParameter.Name = "{?YourParameter}" Then
        CrParameter.AddCurrentValue defaultParameter
    End If
Next CrParameter
```